# TikZ: create filled polygon from single points set

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

I have a list of named points (from `mark-1` to `mark-26`) and I want to use them as vertexes of a polygon, which should be filled blue.

I don't want to write them down in a path manually because they will change in other versions of the document (going from 26 to 20 or something like that).

I've tried this:

```
\newcommand{\aaa}{
    \foreach \x [count=\xi from 2] in {1,...,25} {(mark-\x) -- (mark-\xi)}
};
\fill[blue] \aaa -- (mark-1) -- cycle;
```

but it seems that `\aaa` catches just the last 2 points (25 and 26).

Update:
Since the answer requires some details, I'm generating the nodes using decorations along a path:

```
\begin{scope}[
          every path/.style={
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=between positions 0.57 and 1.2 step 6pt with {
                    \node[
                          red,
                          %nodes going from mark-1 to mark-26
                          name=mark-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}
                         ] circle (2pt);
                }
            }
          }
]
    % load base compound path
    \input{img/comp}
\end[scope]
```

Thank you

Comment: you are not creating a polygon but a lot of standalone paths. So only the last path is filled.

Comment: Are you trying to draw a polygon of 26 sides?

Comment: definitely, yes.

Answer (score 16):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Create random(ish) points
\foreach \i in {1,...,26}
  \fill [opacity=0.5] (360/26*\i:1+rnd*1) circle [radius=.025] coordinate (mark-\i);

% Join them up
\fill [opacity=0.5,blue]
  (mark-1) \foreach \i in {2,...,26}{ -- (mark-\i) } -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works as standalone example, I've compiled it correctly, but it fails in my context ([img here](http://i.imgur.com/B5r2Jb4.png)). I've updated the question with my code, since I'm generating the `mark-n` points as decoration nodes.