# Filling a polygon defined by `\node` command

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, polygon

I draw a polygon using `\node` in TikZ, and I want to fill the polygon.

When I use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160568/tikz-create-filled-polygon-from-single-points-set) method, it obviously fails because I do not use `\coordinate` to create the polygon.

Is there a way to fill a polygon drawn using `\node`, instead of `\coordinate`?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,tikz,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, fill=white, shape=circle, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=1pt];
        \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, line width=0.3mm, color=red];
        \node (v1) at (2.2,1) {};
        \node (v2) at (2.8,1.3) {};
        \node (v3) at (2.8,1.5) {};
        \node (v4) at (2.2,1.6) {};
        \node (v5) at (1.8,2) {};
        \node (v6) at (1.8,1.5) {};
        \node (v7) at (2.1,1.4) {};
        \draw (v1)--(v2)--(v3)--(v4)--(v5)--(v6)--(v7)--(v1);

        \fill [opacity=0.5,gray]
            (v1) \foreach \i in {2,...,7}{ -- (v\i) } -- cycle;     
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A simple polygon.}
        \label{fig:vgPoints}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just the idea : use the centers of the points created by the nodes and connect them with a draw command and a `fill=yourColor` with opacity or not.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,tikz,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, fill=white, shape=circle, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=1pt];
        \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, line width=0.3mm, color=red];
        \node (v1) at (2.2,1) {};
        \node (v2) at (2.8,1.3) {};
        \node (v3) at (2.8,1.5) {};
        \node (v4) at (2.2,1.6) {};
        \node (v5) at (1.8,2) {};
        \node (v6) at (1.8,1.5) {};
        \node (v7) at (2.1,1.4) {};
        \draw[opacity=0.5,fill=gray] (v1.center)--(v2.center)--(v3.center)--(v4.center)--(v5.center)--(v6.center)--(v7.center)--(v1.center);

        \fill [opacity=0.5,gray]
            (v1) \foreach \i in {2,...,7}{ -- (v\i) } -- cycle;     
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A simple polygon.}
        \label{fig:vgPoints}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome... Happy TeXing